Why would setting "save as activity" to true throw "duplicate value found" exception when sending an email with a template?
First thing first, I have gone through this thread where "duplicate value" is discussed - How to debug the mysterious "duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>" error
Sending SingleEmail message with 2 different EmailTemplates , one fails, other works. Here are 2 SingleEmail messages.
Works
DEBUG|mail Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=(mitesh@test.com, support@gocloudz.com);getCcAddresses=null;getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=null;getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=null;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=0D2F7000000xxxxx;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=0030k0000158xxxxx;getTemplateId=00X0k000000dxxxxx;getTemplateName=Lightning - Email template with Attachment;getToAddresses=(mitesh@test.com);getWhatId=006xxx

Throws Error
DEBUG|mail Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[getBccAddresses=(mitesh@test.com, support@gocloudz.com);getCcAddresses=null;getCharset=null;getEntityAttachments=null;getFileAttachments=null;getHtmlBody=null;getInReplyTo=null;getOptOutPolicy=SEND;getOrgWideEmailAddressId=0D2F70000004Gxxxxx;getPlainTextBody=null;getReferences=null;getTargetObjectId=0030k0000158exxxxx;getTemplateId=00XF7000000Xzxxxxx;getTemplateName=Classic - Email template with Attachment;getToAddresses=(mitesh@test.com);getWhatId=006xxx

The only difference in above 2 debug statements is the EmailTemplate Id. Not sure why Salesforce will throw "Duplicate Value" for the later template?
== Edit 1 ==
Upon further investigation, it turns out the culprit is mail.setSaveAsActivity(). Below line of code sets the value to true if the whoId is a contact which is supported by Salesforce.
mail.setSaveAsActivity(string.valueOf(whoId).startsWith('003'));

Replacing that with below sends the email but the activity is not shown under ActivityHistory.
mail.setSaveAsActivity(false);

Wondering why mail.setSaveAsActivity(true) would throw "duplicate value found" exception
== Edit 2 ==
Found the root cause, it is related to Salesforce Messaging class. Below code throws "duplicate value found"
mail.setTemplateId(emailTemplateId);

however, replacing that with renderStoredEmailTemplate works just fine and it also stored the activity history
mail = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(emailInfo.EmailTemplateId, whoId, whatId);


Did you check what kind of automation you have on the activity that is logged in the org? More often than not this sort of issue can be caused by flows and even managed packages.

there is no automation on the Activity and there are no unique fields on Activity object. It seems the issue is with Mail.Messaging methods. Please see the edited question.
